# MFC app crash - release vs debug

Tags: debugging, windows-7, mfc, windows-xp, release

I wrote an MFC application that have functions of downloading files.

But I met a problem that crashes app.
In windows 7 there is no problem. And also in debug mode it works fine.

In windows xp, in release mode, the app crashes sometimes.
I wonder what is the problem, and want your help.

Regards.

Comment: This is waaay too little information. If you can't debug the release version, at least create a crash dump, and see where the crash actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can sometimes happen, the key is to debug the release version and find where it crashes and fix the issue.

The instructions to debug a release version is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In debug version variables are initialized to some values by default, under release they can be anything. Also some layout can change.

Try running app verifier, it catches 99% of bugs where something overwrites something else.

Comment: Excellent answer, and most likely 100% correct.  Almost ALL debug vs. release crashes I've ever debugged have been variables that are not initialized.  A good app I found for catching stuff like this is CppCheck.  Of course, Purify is probably still the best, but I don't currently own a copy of it, so debugging stack-trashing issues can be a bit of a challenge, but, it always helps to know your x86 assembly.  (Or amd64 assembly, whatever the case may be.)

Answer (score 0):

You should first compare the `Release` and `Debug` configuration.
There is no simple evidences to say why it craches, but it should NOT crash in Release if it works in Debug.

My first impression is that the code is different between the 2 configurations.
For example, a pre-processor define as `#ifdef` must compile a code block that ios not present in other configuration.
Check this point, and **compare your two configuration details**, it will help !